# MP3 AudioEncoding not working, am I currently running v1beta1?

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I am trying to transcribe audio from a stream using this tutorial (section, "Performing streaming speech recognition on a local file"): https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize

The file is an M3U file, so I am trying to use the RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.MP3 option, but the MP3 attribute is being rejected. When I try to autocomplete the option, MP3 does not appear either.

The documentation show that the MP3 attribute is only available in version v1beta1 (https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.texttospeech.v1beta1#google.cloud.texttospeech.v1beta1.AudioEncoding), and I ran the pip upgrade.

Is there something else I need to do to install v1beta1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the second link you shared, regarding `v1beta1`, is for the **Text-to-Speech** API which is the other way around of the examples you are following (**Speech-to-Text** API).

In that case, to use `RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.MP3`, you'll need to use the [`v1p1beta1`](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/RecognitionConfig#audioencoding) version instead. No changes are needed to the pip command (`pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech`) but you need to import the right version (`speech_v1p1beta1`) in your Python code:

```py
# [START speech_transcribe_streaming]
def transcribe_streaming(stream_file):
    """Streams transcription of the given audio file."""
    import io
    from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1
    from google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1 import enums
    from google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1 import types
    client = speech_v1p1beta1.SpeechClient()
```

And now you can use the MP3 encoding:

```py
    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.MP3,
        sample_rate_hertz=16000,
        language_code='en-US')
    streaming_config = types.StreamingRecognitionConfig(config=config)
```

Full code [here](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/a4deaf7f0efa5c4f23e1f3b59088eb72) but it's just the base example with the previous changes.

Tested with an MP3 sample:

```sh
$ python mp3.py sample.mp3
Finished: True
Stability: 0.0
Confidence: 0.9875912666320801
Transcript: I'm sorry Dave I'm afraid I can't do that
```